# Connecting flask-socketio with user_loader

Tags: flask, flask-login, flask-socketio

Warning: Apologies for the long post

We are currently running a flask server with a couchdb backend.  We have a few API endpoints that provide user information.  We've used flask-login for user management.  THe user_loader checks the user database on each request:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    mapping = g.couch.get('_design/authentication')
    mappingDD = ViewDefinition('_design/authentication','auth2',mapping['views']['userIDMapping']['map'])
    for row in mappingDD[id]:
        return userModel.User(row.value)
```

We also have a segment that has a websocket to enable chat between the server and the client.  The code below I took after seeing the authentication section of the flask-socketio documentation:

```
def authenticated_only(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        if not current_user.is_authenticated:
            disconnect()
        else:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
```

I have the following code for my web socket:

```
@app.route('/sampleEndPoint/')
def chatRoom():
    return render_template('randomIndex.html', async_mode=socketio.async_mode)

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
@authenticated_only
def test_connect():
    app.logger.debug(session)
    emit('my_response', {'data': 'Connected'})

@socketio.on('disconnect_request', namespace='/test')
@authenticated_only
def disconnect_request():
    session['receive_count'] = session.get('receive_count', 0) + 1
    emit('my_response',{'data': 'Disconnected!', 'count': session['receive_count']})
    disconnect()

@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/test')
@authenticated_only
def test_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected', request.sid)
```

Everything works well in the other routes.  However, I get the following error when I connect to the websocket:

> File "/home/sunilgopikrishna/insurance_brokerage/perilback/main.py",
>   line 144, in load_user
>       mapping = g.couch.get('_design/authentication')   File "/home/sunilgopikrishna/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py",
>   line 343, in **getattr**
>       return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name) AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'couch'

I read in the flask-socketio documentation that login_required does not work with socketio.

Is there a workaround for this?  Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Galeej

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read in the flask-socketio documentation that login_required does not work with socketio

Sure, but you are not using `login_required` in your socketio events, so that is not the problem here.

The problem is that you probably have a `before_request` handler that sets `g.couch`. The "before" and "after" handlers only run for HTTP requests, they do not run for Socket.IO, because in this protocol there is no concept of requests, there is just a single long-term connection.

So basically, you need to find another way to access your database connection in your user loader handler that does not rely on a `before_request` handler.

Comment: Hi Miguel, I went through some of your answers on the github repo... I did the following: 1. I first removed the url for the websocket in the user_loader to disable the websocket hitting the user_loader everytime and 2. I removed all forms of authentication and stored the necessary variables as session variables.  Since a user has to login when he/she hits the websocket, things are ok for now :).